# Wamp issue for testing upload PHP file

Tags: php, wamp

I'm trying to learn how to upload by using Wamp server..
But unsure is it the settings or my code.

Please enlighten me.

Upload.htmlS

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="http://localhost/testing/php/file_uploader.php" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The uploader.php

```
<?php
if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" )
{
   copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "C:\wamp\www\beta\images" ) or 
           die( "Could not copy file!");
}
else
{
    die("No file specified!");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Uploading Complete</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Uploaded File Info:</h2>
<ul>
<li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'];  ?>
<li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['size'];  ?> bytes
<li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['type'];  ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The error i've received is ,

```
Warning: copy(bannerbelow.JPG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\beta\admin\php\file_uploader.php on line 4
```

Comment: have you checked beta and images folder exists ?

Comment: @RahulMishra, yes 
It's under C:\wamp\www\beta\images.

Comment: As a side remark, security best-practices advise to store all user uploads OUTSIDE of the webroot and access it through a dedicated handler. it also comes with other advantages like the ability to log/restrict access to files based on user authentication for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php
    if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" ) {
        $uploadfolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/beta/images";
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "$uploadfolder/$filename" ) or 
               die( "Could not copy file!");
    }
    else {
        die("No file specified!");
    }
?>
```

Comment: You have no error checking in this code. Error checking is always a good idea.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Totally true. But I was not making a tutorial, just solving a problem :) Here is a tutorial that shows how to check for the file type, and check whether the file was successfully uploaded without causing an error: http://www.sitepoint.com/file-uploads-with-php/

Comment: Sorry I intended to comment that on the questioners post, not yours

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = 'C:\wamp\www\beta\images\'; // make sure dir is exist 

if(!is_dir($path)){
   mkdir($path)
}

//write code for move file  via copy or move_uploaded_file funcition
```